# Getting player rank from database

Tags: sql, mysql, rank

I have a RuneScape private server, which stores the player scores in a database.
The highscores load the player's scores and put them into a table.

But now comes the harder part I can't fix:
I want to display the rank of the player. Like: 'Attack level: 44, ranked 12'.  So it has to find the rank the user has.

How can I get this to work? I googled for 2 days now, I did not find anything.

Comment: Are the user levels stored in another table in the MySQL database? Perhaps you could use PHPMyAdmin or SQLYog Community to comb through the data you have access to.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a way to achieve this using the same query.

You could make another query like:

pos = `select count(*) from players where attack > 44` + 1

This query would return the number of players ranked above someone. The "plus one" part is to make the rank start at 1 (because the first one won't have anyone ranked above him).

For example, if the table is:

```
id attack
 0     35
 1     22
 2    121
 3     76
```

pos(3) = 1 (only player 2 is ranked above) + 1 = 2

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view (probably) that shows every players score. Something along these lines might work.

```
create view player_scores as 
select player_id, sum(score) 
from scores
group by player_id
```

That will give you one row per player, with their total score. Having that view, the rank is simple.

```
select count(*) 
from player_scores
where sum > (select sum from player_scores where player_id = 1)
```

That query will return the number of players having a higher score than player_id = 1.

Of course, if you know your player's score before you run the query, you can pass that score as a parameter. That will run a lot faster as long as the column is indexed.